# Scroll div to the top doesn't work on Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I have a div that has independent scrollbars. At some point, I'm trying to make it scroll to the top of it's container by using this line:

```
document.getElementById('page-content').scroll(0,0);
```

That works great on Firefox, but not on Safari/Chrome. It says that scroll is `undefined`

If I just use

```
scroll(0,0);
```

Then it works everywhere, but of course it's not what I need.

If I can avoid using jQuery even better.

Comment: try `document.getElementById('page-content').scrollTop = 0;`

Comment: @Pete, this worked great. Please make it into an answer so I can choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
document.getElementById('page-content').scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: this does not work for me in Safari, only in Chrome does. Is there a reason?

Comment: What version of safari and os are you using?

Comment: Safari 5.1.7...there are a lot of div but they don't scroll

Comment: Is that for windows - if so then apple dropped support for that browser in 2012 as it wasn't very good.  I would also stop trying to program for it as it won't be compliant and probably won't support many of the new html5 and css3 features

Comment: Yes, I'm using Safari for Windows 7 but I am not sure the problem is that because that js instruction works fine in other web apps we developed. I don't know what problem could be in this case, maybe some CSS rules...